# Can Wife celebrate Eid with her parents?

Tags: sharia, nikah, eid

Salam alikum, bro an sis. I have question. Me and wife are staying aboard and we are going to India. As it will be EidAdha time at that moment, my wife wants to celebrate this with her family with my kid. I want her to celebrate with me and my parents. Not sure what to do. Her family and my family is staying in different cities.. Is her this demand is correct.l?

Comment: The answer to this question should be a short "Yes, she can." However, to get a more elaborate answer, you might want to share more things regarding your situation. Where do you usually celebrate Eid? Any specific reason why she wanted to celebrate Eid with her parents? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of personal opinion, thus it might be not the answer you are looking for.
It’s her right to see her family and your right to see yours, and since both of you live abroad, it’s good chance for her to be with them, and so for you.

It’s also the kid’s right to see both families.
The only thing comes to my mind is Allah saying:

> Indeed, Allah orders justice and good conduct and giving to relatives
>   and forbids immorality and bad conduct and oppression. He admonishes
>   you that perhaps you will be reminded. 16/90

Reach an agreement with your wife to fairly dividing the time for the three of you to see both families, and remember she left her family to be with you far from home, so reward her as much as you can.